# Flagging as 1 n consecutive rows when a condition is met

Tags: loops, if-statement

Assume I have a list that contains either 0 or 1.

Next to this one (call it `ColA`), I want to add a column (call it `ColB`) which takes the following values:

i.  if `ColA` == 1, then the next `n` rows in `ColB`  should be flagged with 1

ii. if `ColA` == 0, then the corresponding row in `ColB` should be flagged with 0 unless it is one of those `n` rows subsequent a 1 in `ColA`

Can anyone suggest a sketch of code/an idea of how to achieve this?

Any solution in R, SQL, Python or C++ is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in R:

```
for (i in (1:nrow(db))){
    if (db$ColA[i] != 0){
        for (j in (i:(n+i-1))){
            db$ColB[j] <- 1
        }
    } 
}
```